# How to create BigQuery Data Transfer w/ Python + Service Account?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a *new* data transfer job in BigQuery using Python and [google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquerydatatransfer/latest/gapic/v1/api.html) but I run into the error:

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 User does not have sufficient permission: bigquery.transfers.update is required on project PROJECT_ID

I've included my code below which isn't terribly interesting. I am running this while setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/secrets/service-account.json`. This service account has *Owner* status because I thought that upping its privileges might get me past the permissions error.

Now I'm starting to think that this API doesn't work at all with a service account, or am I crazy? I see `authorization_code` and `CheckValidAuth` in the documentation but it says they're optional.

**Does the Google BigQuery Data Transfer API work with service accounts?**

---

```py
import os
import boto3
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer_v1
import google.protobuf.json_format

client = bigquery_datatransfer_v1.DataTransferServiceClient()

parent = client.project_path('PROJECT_ID')

transfer_config = {
    "destination_dataset_id": "neilo",
    "display_name": "NeilO Data Transfer Test",
    "data_source_id": "amazon_s3",
    "params": {
        "destination_table_name_template": "test_table",
        "data_path": "s3://bucket/path/to/files/*.csv.gz",
        "access_key_id": os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        "secret_access_key": os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
        "file_format": "CSV"
    },
    "schedule": "daily"
}

transfer_config = google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict(
    transfer_config, bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.TransferConfig())

response = client.create_transfer_config(parent, transfer_config)
```

The problem is

Comment: Can you ensure that this service account has granted `bigquery.transfers.update` and `bigquery.transfers.get` permissions?

Comment: Yes, I even applied the _Owner_ role which includes full permissions to everything in BigQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I mistyped `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` when I set it so I was inadvertently using the *wrong* service account. I added the following code to verify the correct project:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
assert bigquery.Client().project == 'PROJECT_ID'
```

I also made sure that the service account has the `bigquery.transfers.update` permission using the minimal [built-in role](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles) of *Editor*:

[image: built-in Roles supporting bigquery.transfers.update permission]